# TFS Back up failed : Timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I am trying to take the tfs back up. But its getting failed .

I will  add the exception details here from the log file generated .

[Error  @12:41:51.187] Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Backup failed for Server 'sampledb-tfs-ser'.  ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)

I know server is timing out .  is der any way to increase the time out or any other way in which this problem could be solved ..?

Can any one help please  ...?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using some sort of programming language (C#, powershell, etc) to do this.  You're going to have to set the query timeout for your connection to 0 to let the program wait indefinitely for the backup to finish.  How you go about doing that depends on the language,  The ServerConnection class has a property called StatementTimeout.  Set that to 0 and you should be good to go.

Comment: No i am not using any kinda language . These is a option "Take full Back up Now " in TFS admin console . I am just clicking on that.

Comment: Right.  So what's that using behind the scenes?  The fact that it's coming back with an SMO error indicates that it's doing it with .NET code somehow.

Comment: This is using TFS powertools backup plan

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.  I found this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2010/09/29/known-issues-with-the-backup-restore-power-tool.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

On your TFS APPTier server,  in file 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\ConfigPT.xml 
, try changing the value of property

```
<SqlStatementTimeoutInSeconds>21600</SqlStatementTimeoutInSeconds>
```

Try 12 hours (43200) instead.  That solved the problem for me.

This file is the result of executing the TFS backup plan in the "Team Foundation Administration Console".  Therefore you may have to change that value everytime after re-executing the TFS backup plan.